# How to compile polkadot node with only rococo runtime

Tags: polkadot, rococo-local, features, compile

When I build polkadot with `cargo build --release` it builds all the runtimes including Polkadot, Kusama, Rococo, Westend. This is a lot to compile and most of it is not needed.

In my case, I'm testing a parachain locally, so I only need the rococo runtime. I remember there is a way to compile only that runtime, and I even see the `rococo-native` feature in `sc-cli` but I can't remember how to build the node with only that runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile the `rococo-runtime` package and its dependencies with `cargo build --release -p rococo-runtime`. On master this compiles 638 packages instead of the full 1819, and is a flag that you can use for any individual package in the workspace to save time in the future.

From `cargo build --help`:

```
-p, --package [<SPEC>]  Package to build (see `cargo help pkgid`)
```

You can find the full list of the workspace members in `Cargo.toml` in the root of the repo, and their respective package names in the corresponding `Cargo.toml` in the directory of the package.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with the latest code.

It's a feautre of its dependency.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/76994356fcaeda77a5c21958ef4e2597e1c74b05/polkadot/Cargo.toml#L29

You can modify the code to remove the `westend-native` then `cargo build --release -p polkadot`.